# Two ways of build html -- .html() and .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery, I know we can replace an object's HTML using `.html(html code here)`, and we can also use one of the methods (`append`, `appendTo`, `prepend`, etc.) to achieve the same goal of `.html(...)`.

But what is the difference between these two ways?

**Updated**

I think I should post my code to make my question more clearly, please review it.

```
$('<a>close</a>').click(function() {
            alert("test");
        }).appendTo($('.widget-head'));

var sHtml = $('.widget-head').wrap('<p>').parent().html();
$(currentTmpContainer).html(resultHtml);
```

(This is just a code snippet. I think you would be okay understanding it. Thanks.)
Finally, I found that `.click` didn't work in my example. I guess the reason is because I am using `.html()` instead of `.append()`. Is it correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `.html()` won't copy the jQuery events, if you want to copy you should use `.clone(true)`, if you want to replace, use `append`.

Comment: @gdoron Thanks, `.append` is replace the original html?

Comment: If you take an existing node and append it to a different location it will "relocate" it, not clone it.

Comment: @gdoron ok , I got it . Just only one exist .thanks. In my case I think I don't have any reason to use `.clone(true)`. I just need to build an object and "relocate" it . thanks your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With `.html` you override the content, while with `.append` you add the content to the end of tag.
2. `html` accepts a raw string only, with `append` you can using jQuery object as well.

Example:

```
$('#foo').html($('<input>')); //invalid!
$('#foo').append($('<input>')); //Valid!
```

With events:

```
var $input = $('<input>').click(function(){
    alert('foo');
});

$('#foo').append($input);
```

Comment: Seems the `.html()` can not attach an event. But `append` can attach the event in advance. Am I right ? I am not familiar with this part , hope you  tell me more about this. thanks.

Comment: @Joe.wang - `append()` is directly manipulating the DOM, while `html()` is just changing the HTML code.

Comment: @Joe.wang, yes, you're right, that can not be done with `html` unless you use inline code with `onclick` attributes, Yuck.

Comment: @gdoron - You were missing a `)` at the end ;)

Comment: @gdoron Could you please help to review it again ? I updated it .thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use .html() for changing the text of an element.  E.g.

```
$('.myElement').html('Hello, World!');
```

Which results in something like

```
<p class='myElement'>Hello, World!</p>
```

I use .append() to add new element to an existing one. E.g.

```
$('.myElement').append($('<span>Inner Element!</span>'));
```

Which results in

```
<p class='myElement'><span>Inner Element!</span></p>
```

The reason I use .append() is that it allows me to use jQuery to build on the new element.  E.g.

```
var newElement = $('<span>Inner Element!</span>').click(function(e){ alert("Hello!"); });
$('.myElement').append(newElement);
```